# How can I make the scrollbar drag with the mouse?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My form'),
      ),
      body: new Scrollbar(
        child: TextField(
          maxLines: 99999,
        ),
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        controller: ScrollController(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm making Windows and Web apps with Flutter.
I want to be able to drag the scroll bar of the input field with the mouse.
But with this code I do nothing when I drag the bar with the mouse.
How can I drag it?
Flutter's SDK is Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.380.

Comment: Maybe use a package ? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_scrollbar

Comment: @ValdaXD Thank you for the information. However, it seems that it is not practical because the sample has a problem that the bar does not move even if it scrolls.